# How to get stats from ConnectedComponentsWithStats in EmguCv

Tags: c#, emgucv, connected-components

I'm working on pedestrians detection algorithm and got stuck on using `ConnectedComponentsWithStats()` method. I can't get to the values of stats. Here is what I wrote so far:

```
var labels = new Mat();
var stats = new Mat();
var centroids = new Mat();
var nLabels = CvInvoke.ConnectedComponentsWithStats(greyImage, labels, stats, centroids);

var centroidPoints = new MCvPoint2D64f[nLabels];
centroids.CopyTo(centroidPoints);

foreach (MCvPoint2D64f point in centroidPoints)
{
   var x = point.X;
   var y = point.Y;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The stats are stored as int32's in opencv c++ and have 5 fields x,y,width,height and area.

You can see the opencv implementation of [ConnectedComponentsWithStats here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/cd2b188c9a55c3b2b2fbfb16493cfbb6532ab0b4/modules/imgproc/src/connectedcomponents.cpp#L4021).
Also you can see the [struct CCStatsOp opencv returns the stats as here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/cd2b188c9a55c3b2b2fbfb16493cfbb6532ab0b4/modules/imgproc/src/connectedcomponents.cpp#L90).

Sadly EMGUCV has not created the data structure CCStatsOp so you will need to just store the raw integer data like such.

```
  int[] statsData = new int[stats.Rows * stats.Cols];
  stats.CopyTo(statsData);
  for (int i = 0; i < stats.Rows; i++)
  {
    var x = statsData[i * stats.Cols + 0];
    var y = statsData[i * stats.Cols + 1];
    var width = statsData[i * stats.Cols + 2];
    var height = statsData[i * stats.Cols + 3];
    var area = statsData[i * stats.Cols + 4];
  }
```

You can also roll your own CCStats op with this code here.

Struct

```
public struct CCStatsOp
{
  public Rectangle Rectangle;
  public int Area;
}
```

Code

```
  var labels = new Mat();
  var stats = new Mat();
  var centroids = new Mat();
  var nLabels = CvInvoke.ConnectedComponentsWithStats(greyImage, labels, stats, centroids);

  var centroidPoints = new MCvPoint2D64f[nLabels];
  centroids.CopyTo(centroidPoints);

  CCStatsOp[] statsOp = new CCStatsOp[stats.Rows];
  stats.CopyTo(statsOp);
  foreach (var statop in statsOp)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"Rectangle: {statop.Rectangle} Area: {statop.Area}");
  }
```